# Matlab: Timer encounters error on non-structure array

Tags: matlab, user-interface

Trying to use Timer in GUI. While attempting in following code it is showing error.

```
function main_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
handles.output = hObject;
handles.timer   = timer(...
'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...       % Run timer repeatedly
'Period', 1, ...                        % Initial period is 1 sec.
'TimerFcn', {@send_Callback,hObject});
guidata(hObject, handles);

function send_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
comma      = get(handles.Tx_send, 'String');%Tx_send is a text field
TxText     = char(comma);
sf         = rc4e2(TxText,key);%rc4e2 is an encryption
key        = TxText;
DBC        = char(sf);
disp(DBC);
fwrite(handles.serConn, DBC);%serConn is COM port
```

**The error:** Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-1'. Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your timerFcn to `{'send_Callback',handles}`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, This time it shows: Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-1'. Too many input arguments.

Comment: Oh right. You have to remove the @ sign and put the function name in quotes. I corrected it above.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. But "Undefined function 'send_Callback' for input arguments of type 'timer'" - is the new error.

Comment: Try removing hObject as an argument.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, seems like I am stuck in same place. It still shows the same error message as the last message.

Answer (score 0):

In your version (as written in the original question), you have to write

```
'TimerFcn', {@send_Callback,handles});
```

The reason MATLAB is showing this error is because when it calls the Callback function, it automatically passes the timer handle as first argument and an empty event structure as second argument. The argument you provide by using the cell array is the third one. This means, your send_Callback is called with the argument list `handles.timer,event,hObject` (in this case, hObject is the window handle).

Then in the Callback function, you try to access `handles.Tx_send`, but since `handles` is the third argument and you provided just the window handle as the third argument, MATLAB will try to access `handles.output.Tx_send`, which does not exist.

Passing `handles` as described above should solve your problem because then the callback will have access to the `handles` object.